# Trouble decrypting bcrypt bfe file in Java

Tags: java, encryption, bcrypt, blowfish

I have a file that was encrypted using the bcrypt tool on linux and I need to decrypt this file in Java. From what I understand, bcrypt uses some form of Blowfish encryption but I'm not sure how I should be configuring my Cipher instance in Java. I'm currently configuring it to Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding, I've tried a couple other variations of that and also just Blowfish on its own but nothing works.

The following code that I have implemented already executes OK but the output does not match what I get if I simply use the bcrypt tool to decrypt, all I get out of this code is gibberish:

```
String result = null;
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
SecretKeySpec ks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "Blowfish");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, ks);
if (reader != null)
{
    InputStream is = getInputStream(reader);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
    int off = 0;

    while (is.read(bytes, 0, 8) != -1)
    {
        builder.append(new String(cipher.update(bytes, off, 8), "UTF-8"));
    }
    result = builder.toString();
}
```

Does anybody have any experience with this? I've searched far and wide through Google but haven't been able to find anything that fixes it.

Comment: I guess the first goal is to turn "*bcrypt uses some form of Blowfish encryption*" into a more concrete definition. Do you have any links to where you found this information? Without knowing exactly how the encryption is performed, you are stuck.

Comment: Yeah I realise this, I've also been looking for that. There's nothing on the bcrypt man pages and the 'more information' links on the sourceforge pages are broken.

http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/

Also, encryption and security are not my forte so it is quite possible that I've missed something.

Comment: In which case, you may be best ignoring this question for now and seeking further information (probably on another SE site) about the details of the encryption scheme used by bcrypt.